# ReactCSSTransitionGroup not animating height

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, reactcsstransitiongroup

Im trying to create a simple 'slide down' animation for some content that is hidden/shown based on a state prop. The content is dynamic so the height is unknown.

This is what I tried. Also see this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oykxv7yzq)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class Some extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showMore: false
  }
  render() {
    const {showMore} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Hej verden</h1>
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example"
            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>

          {showMore && 
            <p key={1}>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet. </p>
          }

          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({showMore: !this.state.showMore})
  }

}

export default Some
```

My styles:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.example-enter {
  height: 0;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  height: 100%;
  transition: height 500ms ease;
}

.example-leave {
  height: 100%;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 300ms ease;
}
```

I tried following but nothing worked:

- setting initial height of 0
- used absolute px values for height (although it's not work with dynamic content)
- used `!important` on height
- used `max-height` instead of `height`

How can I make the lorem ipsum content "slide down" from height: 0 to full height?

Comment: Got it to work with velocity-react and a css animation. Can this be done easier? And what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding a base class with `overflow: hidden`.

As demonstrated in the following [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-transition-group-demo).

Without `overflow: hidden` it appears as if the transition doesn't take place at all.

Comment: The default is `overflow: visible`, you'll still see the children nodes, even if the parent node height transitions to 0. If you set a background color on the node,  you should be able to see the transition taking place.